# How to write a legend description of the long table (at the bottom) in latex?

Tags: captions, longtable

I use long table in overleaf across multiple pages. However, I need to put single-spacing caption description below the table. In principle, I want to describe the table legend. I would like my caption title to be at the begining of the table (field requirement) and caption description (description of the table legend) bellow the table (at the table end).

Anyone knows how to do it?

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary} % Automatic table sizing
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx, array, blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}
        \LTcapwidth=\textwidth
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.58}
    \begin{longtable}{c c c} 
    \caption{Chemical similarity between selected analogs and KGA inhibitors.} 
    \label{tab:61analogs}
    
    %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}\\
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}\\
    %\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{To ZINC00000169698697} & \textbf{To other inhibitors} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    25019940 & 0.58 & 0.47 \\
    5164097 & 0.66 & 0.48 \\
    1738866 & 0.62 & 0.47 \\
    20105225 & 0.62 & 0.49 \\
    3110202 & 0.75 & 0.45 \\
    3110206 & 0.73 & 0.62 \\
    4867157 & 0.69 & 0.54 \\
    4304409 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
    5151381 & 0.76 & 0.49 \\
    3101013 & 0.73 & 0.53 \\
    3100996 & 0.71 & 0.53 \\
    3101001 & 0.71 & 0.36 \\
    19165041 & 0.60 & 0.55 \\
    74982828 & 0.95 & 0.59 \\
    2959312 & 0.62 & 0.42 \\
    25287769 & 0.54 & 0.42 \\
    25287770 & 0.54 & 0.51 \\
    5222294 & 0.65 & 0.60 \\
    1256772 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
    5080634 & 0.66 & 0.59 \\
    1146140 & 0.69 & 0.35 \\
    5081393 & 0.58 & 0.41 \\
    3463344 & 0.63 & 0.49 \\
    3649210 & 0.73 & 0.49 \\
    3101002 & 0.73 & 0.48 \\
    3100991 & 0.68 & 0.39 \\
    100382946 & 0.54 & 0.41 \\
    100232025 & 0.53 & 0.35 \\
    124451668 & 0.58 & 0.48 \\
    3720795 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
    16678941 & 0.54 & 0.66 \\
    24593477 & 0.63 & 0.65 \\
    53198065 & 0.68 & 0.48 \\
    4054374 & 0.64 & 0.45 \\
    4573030 & 0.70 & 0.66 \\
    46199646 & 0.43 & 0.41 \\
    1261915 & 0.65 & 0.53 \\
    51065402 & 0.57 & 0.47 \\
    4313682 & 0.63 & 0.46 \\
    40732500 & 0.70 & 0.46 \\
    40732501 & 0.70 & 0.65 \\
    11497983 & 0.64 & 0.52 \\
    20933064 & 0.61 & 0.43 \\
    4387920 & 0.63 & 0.47 \\
    4575072 & 0.65 & 0.42 \\
    40462013 & 0.55 & 0.42 \\
    40462014 & 0.55 & 0.67 \\
    28790638 & 0.73 & 0.67 \\
    28790635 & 0.73 & 0.60 \\
    51134141 & 0.63 & 0.66 \\
    26351270 & 0.65 & 0.57 \\
    16194825 & 0.62 & 0.71 \\
    26324089 & 0.68 & 0.55 \\
    125980034 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
    42176161 & 0.69 & 0.48 \\
    42176160 & 0.68 & 0.67 \\
    24569294 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
    3101014 & 0.71 & 0.48 \\
    3587610 & 0.71 & 0.49 \\
    3100992 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
    995167 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
    \end{longtable}
    \justify{\textbf{Compound ID}, ID of the compound taken from XXX. \textbf{To XXXX}, chemical XXXX values measured between 61 analogs and the most potent XXXXXX. \textbf{To remaining inhibitors}, chemical similarity values measured between 61 XXXX and the remaining 4 XXXX inhibitors.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately your MWE is not complete, please add a documentclass, necessary packages as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` so that we can copy your MWE (Minimal Working Example) and compile it without having to guess anything and help you better.
And welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "caption description". E.g., a single-llne caption, a multiline single-spaced caption, or a single-spaced *legend* that provides some explanatory information for the table (and possibly the table's caption)? And please clarify what you're trying to achieve with `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.58}`. Finallly, is "ZINC00000169698697" a real word?

Comment: I mean to describe the legend. I did not know how to describe the legend in the table. I wanted to describe it in the bottom/end of the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three alternative versions of your table:

In the first one, I used a combination of `longtable` to allow the table to span multiple pages in combination with the `threeparttablex` package for the descriptive text below the table.

[image]

I also included two other alternatives that both make sure the table fits onto a single page by showing not only three columns, but two sets of three column side by side. Since the column's entries are quite narrow, you could introduce linebreaks in the column headers (for example with the help of the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package) and fit the second half of the table right next to the first half. This allows you to save space without having to compress the table's contents. I also used horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package as well as `\addlinespace` in order to provide a guide to the eye and make the table more readable.

[image]

The second alternative makes sure, the table is as wide as the textwidth and the explanatory text is just placed inside of the `table` environment. `\smallskip` adds a small amount of vertical white space between the bottom of the table and the start of the explanatory text.

In the third and last alternative, I kept the table at its natural width and used `threeparttable` in order to make sure the explanatory text below the table is as wide as the table naturally is. I also tried to provide more structure to the descriptive text by starting each item in a new line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]
\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
\footnotesize
\item[]     \textbf{Compound ID}, ID of the compound taken from XXX. 
\textbf{To XXXX}, chemical XXXX values measured between 61 analogs and the most potent XXXXXX. \textbf{To remaining inhibitors}, chemical similarity values measured between 61 XXXX and the remaining 4 XXXX inhibitors.
\end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{c c c} 
    \caption{Chemical similarity between selected analogs and KGA inhibitors.} 
    \label{tab:61analogs}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{To ZINC00000169698697} & \textbf{To other inhibitors} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \insertTableNotes
    \endlastfoot
    25019940 & 0.58 & 0.47 \\
    5164097 & 0.66 & 0.48 \\
    1738866 & 0.62 & 0.47 \\
    20105225 & 0.62 & 0.49 \\
    3110202 & 0.75 & 0.45 \\
    3110206 & 0.73 & 0.62 \\
    4867157 & 0.69 & 0.54 \\
    4304409 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
    5151381 & 0.76 & 0.49 \\
    3101013 & 0.73 & 0.53 \\
    3100996 & 0.71 & 0.53 \\
    3101001 & 0.71 & 0.36 \\
    19165041 & 0.60 & 0.55 \\
    74982828 & 0.95 & 0.59 \\
    2959312 & 0.62 & 0.42 \\
    25287769 & 0.54 & 0.42 \\
    25287770 & 0.54 & 0.51 \\
    5222294 & 0.65 & 0.60 \\
    1256772 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
    5080634 & 0.66 & 0.59 \\
    1146140 & 0.69 & 0.35 \\
    5081393 & 0.58 & 0.41 \\
    3463344 & 0.63 & 0.49 \\
    3649210 & 0.73 & 0.49 \\
    3101002 & 0.73 & 0.48 \\
    3100991 & 0.68 & 0.39 \\
    100382946 & 0.54 & 0.41 \\
    100232025 & 0.53 & 0.35 \\
    124451668 & 0.58 & 0.48 \\
    3720795 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
    16678941 & 0.54 & 0.66 \\
    24593477 & 0.63 & 0.65 \\
    53198065 & 0.68 & 0.48 \\
    4054374 & 0.64 & 0.45 \\
    4573030 & 0.70 & 0.66 \\
    46199646 & 0.43 & 0.41 \\
    1261915 & 0.65 & 0.53 \\
    51065402 & 0.57 & 0.47 \\
    4313682 & 0.63 & 0.46 \\
    40732500 & 0.70 & 0.46 \\
    40732501 & 0.70 & 0.65 \\
    11497983 & 0.64 & 0.52 \\
    20933064 & 0.61 & 0.43 \\
    4387920 & 0.63 & 0.47 \\
    4575072 & 0.65 & 0.42 \\
    40462013 & 0.55 & 0.42 \\
    40462014 & 0.55 & 0.67 \\
    28790638 & 0.73 & 0.67 \\
    28790635 & 0.73 & 0.60 \\
    51134141 & 0.63 & 0.66 \\
    26351270 & 0.65 & 0.57 \\
    16194825 & 0.62 & 0.71 \\
    26324089 & 0.68 & 0.55 \\
    125980034 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
    42176161 & 0.69 & 0.48 \\
    42176160 & 0.68 & 0.67 \\
    24569294 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
    3101014 & 0.71 & 0.48 \\
    3587610 & 0.71 & 0.49 \\
    3100992 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
    995167 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}

    \begin{table}
    \caption{Chemical similarity between selected analogs and KGA inhibitors.} 
    \label{tab:61analogs}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l c c lcc} 
    \toprule
    \thead{Compound\\ ID} & \thead{Second\\ entry} & \thead{Third\\ entry} & \thead{Compound\\ ID} & \thead{Second\\ entry} & \thead{Third\\ entry} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
    25019940 & 0.58 & 0.47  &   24593477 & 0.63 & 0.65  \\
    5164097 & 0.66 & 0.48   &   53198065 & 0.68 & 0.48  \\
    1738866 & 0.62 & 0.47   &   4054374 & 0.64 & 0.45   \\
    20105225 & 0.62 & 0.49  &   4573030 & 0.70 & 0.66   \\
    3110202 & 0.75 & 0.45   &   46199646 & 0.43 & 0.41  \\ \addlinespace
    3110206 & 0.73 & 0.62   &   1261915 & 0.65 & 0.53   \\
    4867157 & 0.69 & 0.54   &   51065402 & 0.57 & 0.47  \\
    4304409 & 0.76 & 0.54   &   4313682 & 0.63 & 0.46   \\
    5151381 & 0.76 & 0.49   &   40732500 & 0.70 & 0.46  \\
    3101013 & 0.73 & 0.53   &   40732501 & 0.70 & 0.65  \\ \addlinespace
    3100996 & 0.71 & 0.53   &   11497983 & 0.64 & 0.52  \\
    3101001 & 0.71 & 0.36   &   20933064 & 0.61 & 0.43  \\
    19165041 & 0.60 & 0.55  &   4387920 & 0.63 & 0.47   \\
    74982828 & 0.95 & 0.59  &   4575072 & 0.65 & 0.42   \\
    2959312 & 0.62 & 0.42   &   40462013 & 0.55 & 0.42  \\ \addlinespace
    25287769 & 0.54 & 0.42  &   40462014 & 0.55 & 0.67  \\
    25287770 & 0.54 & 0.51  &   28790638 & 0.73 & 0.67  \\
    5222294 & 0.65 & 0.60   &   28790635 & 0.73 & 0.60  \\
    1256772 & 0.67 & 0.59   &   51134141 & 0.63 & 0.66  \\
    5080634 & 0.66 & 0.59   &   26351270 & 0.65 & 0.57  \\ \addlinespace
    1146140 & 0.69 & 0.35   &   16194825 & 0.62 & 0.71  \\
    5081393 & 0.58 & 0.41   &   26324089 & 0.68 & 0.55  \\
    3463344 & 0.63 & 0.49   &   125980034 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
    3649210 & 0.73 & 0.49   &   42176161 & 0.69 & 0.48  \\
    3101002 & 0.73 & 0.48   &   42176160 & 0.68 & 0.67  \\ \addlinespace
    3100991 & 0.68 & 0.39   &   24569294 & 0.64 & 0.44  \\
    100382946 & 0.54 & 0.41 &   3101014 & 0.71 & 0.48   \\
    100232025 & 0.53 & 0.35 &   3587610 & 0.71 & 0.49   \\
    124451668 & 0.58 & 0.48 &   3100992 & 0.68 & 0.49   \\
    3720795 & 0.67 & 0.59   &   995167 & 0.64 & 0.44    \\ \addlinespace
    16678941 & 0.54 & 0.66  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \smallskip
    
\textbf{Compound ID}, ID of the compound taken from XXX. 
\textbf{To XXXX}, chemical XXXX values measured between 61 analogs and the most potent XXXXXX. \textbf{To remaining inhibitors}, chemical similarity values measured between 61 XXXX and the remaining 4 XXXX inhibitors.
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Chemical similarity between selected analogs and KGA inhibitors.} 
    \label{tab:61analogs}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c lcc} 
    \toprule
    \thead{Compound\\ ID} & \thead{Second\\ entry} & \thead{Third\\ entry} & \thead{Compound\\ ID} & \thead{Second\\ entry} & \thead{Third\\ entry} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
    25019940 & 0.58 & 0.47  &   24593477 & 0.63 & 0.65  \\
    5164097 & 0.66 & 0.48   &   53198065 & 0.68 & 0.48  \\
    1738866 & 0.62 & 0.47   &   4054374 & 0.64 & 0.45   \\
    20105225 & 0.62 & 0.49  &   4573030 & 0.70 & 0.66   \\
    3110202 & 0.75 & 0.45   &   46199646 & 0.43 & 0.41  \\ \addlinespace
    3110206 & 0.73 & 0.62   &   1261915 & 0.65 & 0.53   \\
    4867157 & 0.69 & 0.54   &   51065402 & 0.57 & 0.47  \\
    4304409 & 0.76 & 0.54   &   4313682 & 0.63 & 0.46   \\
    5151381 & 0.76 & 0.49   &   40732500 & 0.70 & 0.46  \\
    3101013 & 0.73 & 0.53   &   40732501 & 0.70 & 0.65  \\ \addlinespace
    3100996 & 0.71 & 0.53   &   11497983 & 0.64 & 0.52  \\
    3101001 & 0.71 & 0.36   &   20933064 & 0.61 & 0.43  \\
    19165041 & 0.60 & 0.55  &   4387920 & 0.63 & 0.47   \\
    74982828 & 0.95 & 0.59  &   4575072 & 0.65 & 0.42   \\
    2959312 & 0.62 & 0.42   &   40462013 & 0.55 & 0.42  \\ \addlinespace
    25287769 & 0.54 & 0.42  &   40462014 & 0.55 & 0.67  \\
    25287770 & 0.54 & 0.51  &   28790638 & 0.73 & 0.67  \\
    5222294 & 0.65 & 0.60   &   28790635 & 0.73 & 0.60  \\
    1256772 & 0.67 & 0.59   &   51134141 & 0.63 & 0.66  \\
    5080634 & 0.66 & 0.59   &   26351270 & 0.65 & 0.57  \\ \addlinespace
    1146140 & 0.69 & 0.35   &   16194825 & 0.62 & 0.71  \\
    5081393 & 0.58 & 0.41   &   26324089 & 0.68 & 0.55  \\
    3463344 & 0.63 & 0.49   &   125980034 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
    3649210 & 0.73 & 0.49   &   42176161 & 0.69 & 0.48  \\
    3101002 & 0.73 & 0.48   &   42176160 & 0.68 & 0.67  \\ \addlinespace
    3100991 & 0.68 & 0.39   &   24569294 & 0.64 & 0.44  \\
    100382946 & 0.54 & 0.41 &   3101014 & 0.71 & 0.48   \\
    100232025 & 0.53 & 0.35 &   3587610 & 0.71 & 0.49   \\
    124451668 & 0.58 & 0.48 &   3100992 & 0.68 & 0.49   \\
    3720795 & 0.67 & 0.59   &   995167 & 0.64 & 0.44    \\ \addlinespace
    16678941 & 0.54 & 0.66  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
\footnotesize
    \item[]\textbf{Compound ID}, ID of the compound taken from XXX. 
    \item[]\textbf{To XXXX}, chemical XXXX values measured between 61 analogs and the most potent XXXXXX. 
    \item[]\textbf{To remaining inhibitors}, chemical similarity values measured between 61 XXXX and the remaining 4 XXXX inhibitors.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}

    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have some serious skills man/woman. Thank you as you provide an answers to the question I posted.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of the second example in the [@leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616648/how-to-write-a-legend-description-of-the-long-table-at-the-bottom-in-latex/616763#616763) answer (+1) with:

- use `tabularray` package with

  - `talltablr` table
  - `booktabs` tabularray library
  - use of a `\NewTblrTheme`
  - use of a `\NewChildSelector`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
%
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
\SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
\SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
                    }
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachfour}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{4}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
%
   \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
  theme = fancy,
caption = {Chemical similarity between selected analogs and KGA inhibitors.},
  label = {tab:61analogs},
note{a} = {ZINC00000169698697},
                    ]{colspec = {@{} *{2}{l c c} @{}},
                      rowsep =0pt,
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                      row{eachfour} = {belowsep=1ex},
                      }
% columns headers
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=1]{c}{Compound\\ ID}
            & {To\\ ZINC\TblrNote{a}}
                   & {To other\\ inhibitors}
                          & \SetCell[c=1]{c}{Compound\\ ID}
                                        & {To\\ ZINC\TblrNote{a}}
                                               & {To other\\ inhibitors}   \\
    \cmidrule[r=-0.9]{1-3}
    \cmidrule[l=-0.9]{4-6}
% table body
25019940    & 0.58 & 0.47 & 24593477    & 0.63 & 0.65 \\
5164097     & 0.66 & 0.48 & 53198065    & 0.68 & 0.48 \\
1738866     & 0.62 & 0.47 & 4054374     & 0.64 & 0.45 \\
20105225    & 0.62 & 0.49 & 4573030     & 0.70 & 0.66 \\
3110202     & 0.75 & 0.45 & 46199646    & 0.43 & 0.41 \\
3110206     & 0.73 & 0.62 & 1261915     & 0.65 & 0.53 \\
4867157     & 0.69 & 0.54 & 51065402    & 0.57 & 0.47 \\
4304409     & 0.76 & 0.54 & 4313682     & 0.63 & 0.46 \\
5151381     & 0.76 & 0.49 & 40732500    & 0.70 & 0.46 \\
3101013     & 0.73 & 0.53 & 40732501    & 0.70 & 0.65 \\
3100996     & 0.71 & 0.53 & 11497983    & 0.64 & 0.52 \\
3101001     & 0.71 & 0.36 & 20933064    & 0.61 & 0.43 \\
19165041    & 0.60 & 0.55 & 4387920     & 0.63 & 0.47 \\
74982828    & 0.95 & 0.59 & 4575072     & 0.65 & 0.42 \\
2959312     & 0.62 & 0.42 & 40462013    & 0.55 & 0.42 \\
25287769    & 0.54 & 0.42 & 40462014    & 0.55 & 0.67 \\
25287770    & 0.54 & 0.51 & 28790638    & 0.73 & 0.67 \\
5222294     & 0.65 & 0.60 & 28790635    & 0.73 & 0.60 \\
1256772     & 0.67 & 0.59 & 51134141    & 0.63 & 0.66 \\
5080634     & 0.66 & 0.59 & 26351270    & 0.65 & 0.57 \\
1146140     & 0.69 & 0.35 & 16194825    & 0.62 & 0.71 \\
5081393     & 0.58 & 0.41 & 26324089    & 0.68 & 0.55 \\
3463344     & 0.63 & 0.49 & 125980034   & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
3649210     & 0.73 & 0.49 & 42176161    & 0.69 & 0.48 \\
3101002     & 0.73 & 0.48 & 42176160    & 0.68 & 0.67 \\
3100991     & 0.68 & 0.39 & 24569294    & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
100382946   & 0.54 & 0.41 & 3101014     & 0.71 & 0.48 \\
100232025   & 0.53 & 0.35 & 3587610     & 0.71 & 0.49 \\
124451668   & 0.58 & 0.48 & 3100992     & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
3720795     & 0.67 & 0.59 & 995167      & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
16678941    & 0.54 & 0.66 &             &      &      \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, format=plain]{caption}
%\usepackage[format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{ltablex}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{tabulary} % Automatic table sizing
%\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
%\usepackage{graphicx, array, blindtext}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
    \LTcapwidth=\textwidth
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
        \begin{longtable}{c c c} 
            %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}\\
            %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}\\
            %\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{To ZINC00000169698697} & \textbf{To other inhibitors} \\
            \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{3}{c}%
            {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
            \hline
            \endhead
            \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot
            \hline
            \caption{Chemical similarity between selected analogs and KGA inhibitors.} \label{tab:61analogs} % changed position of caption
            \endlastfoot
            25019940 & 0.58 & 0.47 \\
            5164097 & 0.66 & 0.48 \\
            1738866 & 0.62 & 0.47 \\
            20105225 & 0.62 & 0.49 \\
            3110202 & 0.75 & 0.45 \\
            3110206 & 0.73 & 0.62 \\
            4867157 & 0.69 & 0.54 \\
            4304409 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
            5151381 & 0.76 & 0.49 \\
            3101013 & 0.73 & 0.53 \\
            3100996 & 0.71 & 0.53 \\
            3101001 & 0.71 & 0.36 \\
            19165041 & 0.60 & 0.55 \\
            74982828 & 0.95 & 0.59 \\
            2959312 & 0.62 & 0.42 \\
            25287769 & 0.54 & 0.42 \\
            25287770 & 0.54 & 0.51 \\
            5222294 & 0.65 & 0.60 \\
            1256772 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
            5080634 & 0.66 & 0.59 \\
            1146140 & 0.69 & 0.35 \\
            5081393 & 0.58 & 0.41 \\
            3463344 & 0.63 & 0.49 \\
            3649210 & 0.73 & 0.49 \\
            3101002 & 0.73 & 0.48 \\
            3100991 & 0.68 & 0.39 \\
            100382946 & 0.54 & 0.41 \\
            100232025 & 0.53 & 0.35 \\
            124451668 & 0.58 & 0.48 \\
            3720795 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
            16678941 & 0.54 & 0.66 \\
            24593477 & 0.63 & 0.65 \\
            53198065 & 0.68 & 0.48 \\
            4054374 & 0.64 & 0.45 \\
            4573030 & 0.70 & 0.66 \\
            46199646 & 0.43 & 0.41 \\
            1261915 & 0.65 & 0.53 \\
            51065402 & 0.57 & 0.47 \\
            4313682 & 0.63 & 0.46 \\
            40732500 & 0.70 & 0.46 \\
            40732501 & 0.70 & 0.65 \\
            11497983 & 0.64 & 0.52 \\
            20933064 & 0.61 & 0.43 \\
            4387920 & 0.63 & 0.47 \\
            4575072 & 0.65 & 0.42 \\
            40462013 & 0.55 & 0.42 \\
            40462014 & 0.55 & 0.67 \\
            28790638 & 0.73 & 0.67 \\
            28790635 & 0.73 & 0.60 \\
            51134141 & 0.63 & 0.66 \\
            26351270 & 0.65 & 0.57 \\
            16194825 & 0.62 & 0.71 \\
            26324089 & 0.68 & 0.55 \\
            125980034 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
            42176161 & 0.69 & 0.48 \\
            42176160 & 0.68 & 0.67 \\
            24569294 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
            3101014 & 0.71 & 0.48 \\
            3587610 & 0.71 & 0.49 \\
            3100992 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
            995167 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\ \hline
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

What you have to be careful about: you load some packages multiple times, I commented out some packages that were not required as well as I added the option `format=plain` to your first call of the package `caption`.

Loading `\package[UTF8]{inputenc}` should no longer be required if you use a relatively up-to-date version of LaTeX.

One last thing that caught my eyes: your choice of `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.58}` (so currently 0.58) made your longtable really cramped, you might consider allowing a bigger arraystretch (I changed the arraystretch to 1 for demonstration purposes).

Comment: What's the purpose of `longtable` inside of `table`? A `table` can not break across pages, so you could use a regular `tabular` inside of the `table` environment.

Comment: you're right, I updated my MWE accordingly, thank you very much

Comment: If I try to compile your code, I get a "dimension too large" error message, which is caused by the fact that you're not allowing the table to break across pages.

Comment: thank you very much, I updated it accordingly

Comment: You may want to remove/replace the introductory sentence to your answer as it no longer corrensponds to the MWE. You may also want to adjust the part between `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` as the caption "continued from previous page"  on the second page looks quite odd with the actual caption just below it.

Comment: How would you adjust it, as this is the usual approach for longtables if I remember correctly? You are right, in this example you could omit it completely, but if it spans multiple pages (more than just two as in this example) it would be necessary, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hello, how would I approach the problem of describing the table legend at the bottom/end of the table? Caption should present the title of the table, but I want to place description of the table and its legends at the bottom of the table.

Comment: if you add a description and a legend in your original post (so we know what you want to add to your longtable) we can try to help you how to add it

Comment: Thanks, I will add now.

Comment: That is kind of essentially what I asked whether someone knows how to do it :)